# .slideUp() doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, slideup

Here's what I'm trying to do - I have this structure of my page:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="page_banner">
        <canvas id="voucher_canvas"></canvas>
        <div id="div_voucher_img"><img id="voucher_img" src="" /></div>
    </div>

   <div id="content">
        inner divs with contact form...
        <div id="div_send_form"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

When the page is loaded - I'm hiding the #page_banner and `#voucher_canvas` with jQuery:

```
$("#page_banner, #canvas_voucher, #div_print_voucher").hide();
```

When the user fills in the form and clicks on the `#div_send_form`, it should draw a voucher on a canvas, with some of the details he entered, then create an image from that canvas. After that I want to `slideUp()` (hide) the `#content` div and on completion `slideDown()` (show) the `#page_banner` div:

```
$("#content").slideUp(400, function () {
    $("#page_banner, #div_print_voucher").slideDown(1000);
});
```

For some reason it doesn't do the `slideUp()`, but after 400ms just hides the `#content` div and does the `slideDown()` to `#page_banner`.

Why is it happening?

I tried to create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2zDhn/1/), but I guess it doesn't support canvas, so it doesn't exactly work there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem:
The height of the `#content` div was defined in CSS as follows:

```
height:640px !important;
```

The `!important` part was preventing it from sliding up correctly. Once it was removed - everything worked just fine.

Comment: Yeah, generally `important`s are good to avoid. I think of them more as a hack than good practice code.